# how to fix icinga2.service: main proces exited

Tags: icinga2, icingaweb2

Hello i have got one problem with icinga. There is a log.

```
root@fejt-vxp:~# systemctl status icinga2
● icinga2.service - Icinga host/service/network monitoring system
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/icinga2.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/icinga2.service.d
           └─limits.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-08-27 12:06:08 CEST; 37s ago
  Process: 4346 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/icinga2 daemon -e ${ICINGA2_ERROR_LOG} (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
  Process: 4338 ExecStartPre=/usr/lib/icinga2/prepare-dirs /usr/lib/icinga2/icinga2 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4346 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 27 12:06:08 fejt-vxp systemd[1]: Started Icinga host/service/network monitoring system.
Aug 27 12:06:08 fejt-vxp systemd[1]: icinga2.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 27 12:06:08 fejt-vxp systemd[1]: Unit icinga2.service entered failed state.
```

When i wrote `systemctl start icinga2` or `/etc/init.d/icinga2 start`
 without action.

thank you

**Addition:**

Each other applications are ready responding: mysql, apache2

Comment: What's your output when you start the daemon in the foreground? `icinga2 daemon`

Answer (score 0):

the most useful debugging informations why icinga2 does not start you can find in

```
/var/log/icinga2/startup.log
```

or via

```
journalctl -xe
```